# Putting conversation attribute 'scope' with value map['flashScope' -> map['messagesMemento' -> map[[empty]]]]

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

### file: compte-flow.xml

```
<view-state id="annonceColocation" view="mesAnnonces.xhtml">
 <on-render>
 <evaluate expression="userService.listMesAnnonceColocation(annonce,  user.getEmail())" result="flowScope.annonce"/>
 </on-render>
</view-state>
```

### file : MesAnnonces.xhtml

```
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">Titre de mon annonce</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{item.titre}" />
</p:column>
<p:column style="width:35%">
<f:facet name="header">Type de logement</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{item.categorie}" />
</p:column>
```

### File: service.java

```
public List<Annonce> listMesAnnonceColocation( Annonce annonce, String email ) {
    UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByEmail( email );
    return annonceDao.listeAnnonceColocation( user, "Colocation" );
}
```

I can not recover the data, however when I add the data in my database it appears but once the session is closed the data is not displayed. Any idea?

Comment: A better explanation of the problem you are facing can help to answer.

Comment: I can't recover data from database

Comment: Show code for annonceDao.listeAnnonceColocation. Check this list being returned is not empty first.

Comment: it is not empty i'am shur

Comment: Any news about this warning ???